# Configure CSS to add table of contents in side bar?

Tags: css, emacs, org-mode, jemdoc

Disclaimer - I know very little about CSS.

I'm interesting in using [jemdoc](https://jemdoc.jaboc.net/index.html)'s CSS (https://jemdoc.jaboc.net/jemdoc.css) with HTML5 exported from emacs org-mode. However I believe emacs org-mode exports a "table-of-contents" rather than a "menu" (which is generated from a separate file with jemdoc), but I would like it if the table of contents could be displayed in the sidebar like the menu. Can this be modified to accept a table of contents? I believe this is the relevant part of the jemdoc CSS.

```
table#tlayout {
    border: none;
    border-collapse: separate;
    background: white;
}

body {
    background: white;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    margin: 0;
}

#layout-menu {
    background: #f6f6f6;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    width: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#layout-menu td {
    background: #f4f4f4;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#layout-content {
    padding-top: 0.0em;
    padding-left: 1.0em;
    padding-right: 1.0em;
    border: none;
    background: white;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#layout-menu a {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
}

tt {
    background: #ffffdd;
}

pre, tt {
    font-size: 90%;
    font-family: monaco, monospace;
}

a, a > tt {
    color: #224b8d;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px gray dotted;
}

#layout-menu a.current:link, #layout-menu a.current:visited {
    color: #022b6d;
    border-bottom: 1px gray solid;
}
#layout-menu a:link, #layout-menu a:visited, #layout-menu a:hover {
    color: #527bbd;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#layout-menu a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.menu-category {
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    margin-top: 0.8em;
    padding-top: 0.2em;
    padding-bottom: 0.1em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

div.menu-item {
    padding-left: 16px;
    text-indent: -16px;
}
```

Currently I use something like this to display my org-mode at the top of the HTML5 page (which I also copied from another CSS file).

```
#table-of-contents {
    display: table;
    width: 350px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    margin-top: 3ex;    
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
}

#table-of-contents h2 {
    border: 0;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;         
}
```

Comment: Without seeing your actual HTML markup, it's hard to tell what CSS you need to apply to have the desired visual effect.

Comment: https://jemdoc.jaboc.net/index.html doesn't exist

Comment: It's asking about something i.e. https://jemdoc.jaboc.net/index.html which no longer exists.